# What could cause a cumulative slowness that manifests itself as high WindowServer CPU usage in High Sierra?

Tags: performance, high-sierra

My system is a MBPro with the GT750M graphics card, mainly using Chrome/Opera

After a day or two of regular usage, it's clear something is accumulating and eventually causing a slowness that shows itself as high WindowServer CPU usage

It's only high CPU usage on WindowServer, no high ram usages etc. - however, since we can't see the GPU Ram stats, I suspect it could be a persistent GPU memory leak (Closing everything doesn't solve the issue, only a reboot does)

I'm out of ideas myself

(This happened right away after installing High Sierra, a reboot delayed the issue for 1-2 days, it seems to happen again and again, so my theories might be wrong too)

Edit: Seems to be a common issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8122451?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this on the same system by installing the 10.13.2 supplemental update, and then the .104 version of the NVIDIA Driver Manager. (the installers are very picky about versions, so pick whichever matches your OS version here; nothing before .104 installed right for me https://www.tonymacx86.com/nvidia-drivers/ )

Restart, and then switch to the NVIDIA Web Driver from the manager:
[image: nvidia web driver]

*(edit: driver helped for a while but the memory leak came back. sigh. back to not having scaled mode available on external screens...)*

Comment: I've been following this thread: https://discussions.apple.com/message/32852590 - mainly out of curiosity - my conclusion is that the bug is left there intentionally, to boost sales, there are reports of slowness on some AMD devices too - It worked for me, I had to buy a new device and sell my damaged old one