# High Sierra's External Display bug heats Macbook's, damaged my Retina Screen, what can I do?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, bug, gpu, temperature

After installing High Sierra, I noticed GPU related slowness, I initially sought help here: [What could cause a cumulative slowness that manifests itself as high WindowServer CPU usage in High Sierra?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306037/what-could-cause-a-cumulative-slowness-that-manifests-itself-as-high-windowserve) - But later on stumbled onto this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8150105 and easily verified that the issue is related to external displays

Before an external display is connected, the GPU temp is around 55C under use, immediately after an external display is connected, the temperature jumps to 75-80C's (no apps used)

Very recently, I noticed this darkening on my Retina screen, I deduct it's a side effect of the constantly hot temperatures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/stRku.jpg

[image]

Ironically it's been 3 weeks since my warranty expired

On one hand, I want to solve the technical issue, preferably without re-installing the OS

On the other hand, the hardware damage is pretty saddening, but I'm guessing nothing can be done about it since the issue is assumably not widespread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “stadium lighting” you show is usually a backlight issue where the voltage or lamps are not to spec.

It’s highly unlikely that a thermal situation would cause that, but I don’t want to say there’s no chance or you’re wrong unless I could examine the whole Mac.

100C on many internal parts is just fine, so your reported ranges don’t seem at all out of line - especially on 2016 and newer MacBook Pro.

Comment: It's indeed very unusual but the device just sit on a stand with it's lid open since inception, and the stadium lighting, or stage lights as I learned that some call it, only appeared after High Sierra

Comment: You could install Sierra on to an external drive and restart there to convince yourself it's not coincidence and in fact relating to the OS. @KaanSoral

Comment: Thanks for the info, the device is a late 2014 one by the way (the warranty is 3 years here), I'm pretty sure the screen damage is there to stay, if there was a practical way to try Sierra I could, but not sure what it would achieve, It would just verify that the heating is from High Sierra, going to report the bug to apple and see whether I can get any remedy from apple locally, in Turkey

Comment: My macbook pro is older, but when i connect it to the external screen (27” apple display) i close the macbook screen which keeps the temperatures down as it reduces the work....

Comment: @SolarMike thanks for the suggestion, I used the original screen without issues on Sierra, but tried it out of curiosity, it indeed makes a noticeable difference, under load same heating, but with light use, the difference is there - what's bizarre is, after 3 years, the lid doesn't close any more, there's something preventing it from closing but I can't see anything, it's like the machine is somehow deformed while sitting there, which might also explain the "stage lights" - but it's unclear what might have caused it - I think it's still the high heat from 10.13.1 endured 24/7

Comment: It could be the internal display cable

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see if the latest NVIDIA drivers fix the overheating issue. They fixed my GPU performance and overheating problems. Update to 10.13.2 + supplemental (released Jan 8) and then install the most recent driver linked here: https://www.tonymacx86.com/nvidia-drivers/

If you don't have the latest update the installer won't work. They are OS version specific as per https://gfe.nvidia.com/mac-update

*(edit: driver helped for a while but the memory leak came back. sigh. back to not having scaled mode available on external screens...)*